# PowerShell script to list users that are enabled, have never logged on or have not logged on in 60 days

Tags: powershell

I need to use PowerShell to list users that are enabled, have never logged on or have not logged on in 60 days.

The below is what I've come up with having never used PowerShell previously, however clearly there is something wrong in my understanding as it just spouts out a bunch of different error messages.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter { Enabled -eq $true } -Properties LastLogonDate | where { ($_.LastLogonDate.AddDays(60) -lt $(Get-Date)) -or  ( -not $_.LastLogonDate-like "*")) } | Select-Object SamAccountName | Format-Table
```

Comment: Ok. What are the errors?

Comment: `LastLogonDate.AddDays(60)` Cut off AddDays and put it on `(Get-Date).AddDays(-60)`  Additionally remove `-not` and utilize `-notlike` comparison operator instead.  With these changes, you don't need any of those extra parenthesis in the `Where-Object` block.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
Get-ADUser -Filter { Enabled -eq $true } -Properties LastLogonDate | where{ (($_.LastLogonDate.AddDays(60) -lt $(Get-Date)) -or ( -not $_.LastLogonDate-like "*")) } | Select-Object SamAccountName | Format-Table
```

your brackets werent correct, more specifically this bracket is extra

```
( -not $_.LastLogonDate-like "*")) // extra closing bracket
```

Comment: It's not extra.  It encapsulates both ends.

Comment: well not really. I will write a number after every bracket so you can see the pairs `(<1>$_.LastLogonDate.AddDays(<2>60)<2> -lt $(<3>Get-Date)<3>)<1> -or  (<4> -not $_.LastLogonDate-like "*")<4>)<extra>`

Comment: I see. I was looking at your code example instead of OP's.

Comment: so I dont understand the downvote but yeah, glad that we make that clear :)

Answer (score -1):

Taking my comment and making it an answer:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter { Enabled -eq $True } -Properties LastLogonDate |
  #Tests whether LastLogonDate is older than 60 days or if it's $Null
  Where-Object { $_.LastLogonDate -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-60) -or
                 -not $_.LastLogonDate } |
  Select-Object -Property SamAccountName |
  Format-Table
```